# Spreadsheet to import data into Custom Fields Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, import, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I have the following custom fields.

As an example of how they work here is a screenshot of how my custom fields look like when they have data. I added one single dish for the Breakfast section. but this becomes very rough when there are 50 dishes or more.

[image: Screenshot]

So, my question is:
can I create a Spreadsheet file with all the text data of the menus (dishes name, title, prices, description, Subtitle, etc) and then import this file with an Import plugin or a function or anything to import the Spreadsheet file to store the data in the custom fields?

How can I do this? Is it possible? Is it possible to create a template?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. https://www.wpallimport.com/ The pro version will do what you are discussing. The caveat I have found for anyone reading this (and if you have a solution to this please share) but it works great for everything except something that is geolocation based. But for simple fields like this it works great. You'll have to make sure you import your content into the correct fields, and as such I recommend doing a test of one or two before committing to a full import.

Comment: Got it! I actually have wpallimport, but like I am not sure how or what the columns should be in the excel sheet so I can do the import with that plugin. DO you know or do you have a template? thanks in advance

Comment: You just have to name your columns what you would associate for the content. When you're in there uploading it'll have you indicate which columns (and it'll pull the header for your excel file) as the column it'll populate that data to. So I recommend do a *small* run first to make sure before you do a major import. And backup your site before you do any major items in case you need to do a roll back. :)